# Xamarin Prism BindingContext to ViewModel for Intellisense data suggest

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, binding, prism, intellisense

I came from WPF where specifying the DataContext (BindingCntext for Xamarin) the intellisense show me my properties and methods.
Is possible do this with Prism in Xamarin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tooling for Xamarin.Forms still has a long way to go. Using a 3rd party solution like [MFractor](https://www.mfractor.com) it just works. Currently it's only available for VS for Mac, however an edition for Visual Studio on Windows is coming very soon.

As a work around you might use some design time data like:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AwesomeApp.ViewModels"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Class="AwesomeApp.Views.ViewA">
    <d:ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:ViewAViewModel />
    </d:ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Here we have brought in a few XML namespaces for Design, Markup Compatibility, and our ViewModels. Then we specify that anything from the design time is ignorable which means that it is only there for IDE Intellisense and will not be included for our Debug/Release builds. We can then add the BindingContext in DesignTime. Note that it will technically show an error on the ViewModel because it doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

You have two options there. You can ignore it since it's design time and not an actual issue. It will still continue to give you the Intellisense for the properties in the ViewModel. Or you can just add a parameterless constructor. In general this shouldn't be an issue except for the fact that if the container cannot resolve a dependency it may try to use the default constructor instead which would cause all sorts of issues at runtime. At the moment there is no actual Constant in the Design Time build that would allow you to `#if DESIGN_TIME` the parameterless constructor, which is why my recommendation is just ignore the design time warning about the ViewModel.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I've tried your same work around before post the question specifing an xmlns:vm path and using the ContentPage BindingContext = vm:MyViewModel but the error concerning the lack of a constructor without parameters scared me